# PHP - MYSQLI - selecting more than 500000 records - looses connection with mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

**Background :-**

I have a simple table with ~2000000 records.
When I run my queries from command line client I get resuts in decent time with no problem.
I was using doctrine2 but switched to plain mysql queries to test if it is case with doctrine2.

**Problem: -**

When I run same plain SELECT query in PHP script it throws Mysql lost connection error.
Note: It works fine when I limit ( "limit 100" ) results to a lesser number.. say 100 , 1000 , 10000.

**I tried:-**

Incresed below values in my.ini in [mysql] , [mysqld] , [client] sections

*read_buffer_size ,
connect_timeout , 
net_read_timeout ,
max_allowed_packet*

Also *max_execution_time and memory_limit* are good enough to handle data. 0, and 1024M to be exact

FTR I also restarted all the services after making config changes.
Searched all over web with no luck.

Any help?

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: check `max_execution_time` and set it to max_execution_time = 180

Comment: @RuchishParikh PHP max_execution_time is set to 0 already. also the memory limit is way higher than results data

Comment: check max_input_vars in php.ini. FYI: I am not the downvoter.

Comment: No Idea why question is down voted. I asked only after enough research and provided details. OP who down voted this care to explain?

Comment: Thanks @RuchishParikh , but max_input_vars is not relavant here? there is no global variables $_get , $_PSOT etc here. direct hard coded query to select rows from mysql table. " select * from table "

Comment: BTW  @RuchishParikh , Can you please bring it to 0 by upvoting , other people may notice and help.

Comment: yes sure... done :)

Answer (score 1):

No matter what is the cause of your problem - selecting 500K+ records **at once** is poor programming implementation. Better approach is to use `LIMIT` and some sort of front-end pagination - if you want to display the result to the user.

Comment: or use Doctrine's batch approach to manipulate the data: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

Comment: 1. That is not answer and should be a comment. 2. There are more complex use cases than showing data in frontend and paginating like blog examples. 3. My requirement is like that and I need all the data to further process. 4. My questions is extreme case and I am indeed curious why php mysql combo cannot handle mere 500000 records